# ConcurrentHashMap and putAll() method

Tags: java, hashmap, concurrency, concurrenthashmap

Normally (ie. not concurrently), `putAll()` cannot be more efficient than using lot's of calls to `put()`, even assuming that you exclude the cost of building the other Map that you pass to `putAll()`. That's because `putAll()` will need to iterate the passed Map's elements, as well as running through the algorithm for adding each key value pair to the Map that `put()` executes.

But for a ConcurrentHashMap, does it make sense to construct a regular Map and then use `putAll()` to update it? Or should I just do 10 (or 100, or 1000) calls to `put()`?

Does the answer change for multiple calls to `putIfAbsent()`?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you even use threads to fill the ConcurrentHashMap? If not there won't be any difference between a putAll() or 100 consecutive put()'s

Comment: Yes, (at least) one thread is writing to the the ConcurrentHashMap, and multiple threads are reading from it.

Comment: PutAll() is like an automated process for adding multiple elements in CHM, than doing it yourself one by one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first (mostly) threadsafe Map in Java Collections was the synchronized [`HashMap`](http://www.j2ee.me/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) using [`Collections.synchronizedMap()`](http://bit.ly/4adaew). It worked by only allowing one operation at a time. Java 5 added the [`ConcurrentHashMap`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html), which works differently. Basically the [`Map`](http://www.j2ee.me/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) is divided into slices. A [`put()`](http://bit.ly/2D5Moz) operation will only lock the relevant slice. It also added the threadsafe primitives like [`putIfAbsent()`](http://bit.ly/w9lnj).

The reason I explain this is that [`putAll()`](http://bit.ly/4y7HCX) might be more or less efficient depending on how it's implemented. It may work by locking the whole map, which may actually be more efficient than trying to obtain individual locks on every `put()`. Or it may work by doing a bunch of `put()` calls anyway, in which case there's not much difference.

So if it makes sense for your code and you're doing a lot of updates at once, I would use `putAll()` unless it's `putIfAbsent()` that you're after.

**Edit:** I just checked, the Java 6 `ConcurrentHashMap` implements `putAll()` as a loop of `put()` operations so it's no better or worse than doing this yourself.

Comment: I thought it might get one lock for all the updates, but I guess not. I'll just make individual calls to ConcurrentHashMap's `put()` and avoid the cost of building another Map.

Comment: Nice for checking the source, however I content the "no better or worse" as more clear code is more clear code ^^

Comment: It's nice to have clearer code, but to use `putAll()` I'd have to create a new Map (which engenders multiple calls to `put()` anyway).

Comment: @Rudiger: then it makes sense to not create a Map.

Answer (score 2):

`putAll()` just delegates to `put()`. There's no need to build up an intermediate map if you don't have it already. You can see this in the source code, and it doesn't matter what Java implementation you're using, since the code is public domain and shared by all of them.

Note that `putAll()` is not atomic, but merely has the guarantee that each individual `put()` is atomic.